# SEO: How to choose a domain name containing two or more words?

Tags: seo, domains

Suppose if I want to choose a domain name containing two words say - one and two. When it comes to Search Engine Optimization which of the following is the better way of naming the domain?

- onetwo.com
- one-two.com
- one.two.com

Comment: Google no longer rewards domains any extra favoritism with keywords in the domain. You should use a domain that you know your visitors will like, remember and something you can brand.

Comment: Whilst I'm inclined to agree that domain keywords have lost their benefit, it would be good to have some evidence to back this up.

Comment: @bybe Thanks for your answer. Earlier I had asked the same question in an other form and I had received one or two answers that said dividing the words in the domain with a special character is much better. So could you please provide some evidence to support your answer and put it under answer section?

Comment: @AndrewLott yep I somewhat agree with you... Keyword domains do rank well still better than they should however branded domains generally rank better. The major reason why EMD used to rank so high is because anchors created on sites would have the keywords held within. The big nerf to slam EMD domains was the remote anchors, or least from what I've noticed .

Comment: In my opinion keyword in the domain name still helps a lot, I have websites that I barely touched that have keyword in the domain name and are ranking high, while sites where i tried to rank for additional keywords, like putting them in the title of website and content kind of failed to rank for that keyword, so no matter what others, say, if you are looking to be found organicly always use keyword in your domain name. That applies especially if you're just looking to build a small niche site and you don't want to spend eternity on building backlinks to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VERY VERY small aspect you're looking at for SEO. There are many more things you can spend your time on as this does not generally have that much of an impact on SEO. Look at either Moz or Search Metrics' ranking factors to see how far down this is in importance. Technically length of URL is on here but not whether separating words is highly correlated with SEO benefits.

http://www.searchmetrics.com/knowledge-base/ranking-factors-uk/

With domain names, you want to just be sure it makes sense for your visitors and brand.

arnoldschwarzenegger.com is probably not going to do well with people typing in on their phones as the-terminator.com.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the domain that looks the coolest, is the most expensive to acquire and is the most official looking domain just about every time. That's usually going to be two.com/one for me. Hyphens in domains have fallen out of style many years ago. It's also very hard for users to press the hyphen button on their phones which makes accessing your site more difficult.